# Proving that an eigenvalue is a root of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of A.  Prove that if $p$ is a polynomial such that $p(A)=\mathbb{0}$ then $\lambda$ is a root of $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ then there's $v$ such that
$$Av=\lambda v$$
and let
$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$
then it's easy to see  by induction that
$$A^kv=\lambda^k v$$
hence
$$0=p(A)v=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k A^kv=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \lambda^kv=P(\lambda)v$$
hence since $v\ne0$ then
$$P(\lambda)=0$$

Comment: Smooth...${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

If $v$ is a corresponding eigenvector then

$0=p(A)v=p(\lambda)v$.